# Polynomial with real coefficients, degree $8$, $8$ pairwise distinct complex roots. Conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

$p$ is polynomial with real coefficients of degree $8$.  $p$ has $8$ pairwise distinct roots.  Then
**a**.   it is possible that $p$ has exactly $3$ pairwise distinct real roots.
**b.**  it is possible that $p$ has exactly $4$ pairwise distinct real roots.
**c.** it is possible that $p$ has no real roots and exactly one root of $p$ has zero real part ($Re(z)=0$).

**a.** No, it is not possible. Due to the fact that coefficient are real it must be $f(z)=0\Rightarrow f(\overline{z}) = 0$.  So there is even number of complex roots - so also even number of real roots.
**b.**  Yeah, it is possible: $p(x)=(x-i)(x+i)(x-2i)(x+2i)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$
**c.** it is not possible.  If $p(ai)=0$ then also $p(\overline{ai})=p(a\overline{i})=0$.

Am I ok ?

Comment: Everything alright :)